# backbone js routing - a url as a parameter

Tags: backbone.js, router

I'm trying to pass a URL as a parameter to the backbone router class but it just won't trigger the callback, when passing non-url string, it does trigger it.

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "myurl/:url": "myurl"
  },

  myurl: function(url) {
    alert('parameter passed: ' + url);
  },

});
```

it works well when linking to

```
 #/myurl/hello-world
```

but nothing happens when linking to

```
#/myurl/http://www.somewebsite.com/folder?withparameter=123
```

Comment: try encoding the uri using encodeURI function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. replace :parameter with *parameters so in my case:

```
routes: {
    "myurl/:url": "myurl"
  },
```

should be

```
routes: {
    "myurl/*url": "myurl"
  },
```